# How to load remote images using Titanium Alloy

Tags: imageview, titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

So I've been trying to load a remote image using titanium, here's a snippet that I'm using, but it always shows the default image. Any clue what I am doing wrong, I'm sorry it's a naive question

here's my view

```
<View id="image">

</View>
```

and my controller

```
userImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            id : "userImage",
            image : "http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~henrik/images/imgs/face_bssrdf.jpg",
            width : 90,
            center:0,
            height : 90,
        });
    $.image.add(userImage);
```

had to upgrade the sdks was buggy at 4.0.0.RC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me with 4.0.0.GA and 4.1.0.GA:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'green'
});

var userImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    id: "userImage",
    image: "http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~henrik/images/imgs/face_bssrdf.jpg",
    width: 90,
    center: 0,
    height: 90,
});

win.add(userImage);

win.open();
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yep, was a bug at 4.0.0.RC